# Automated Encryption Keys

Tags: networking, encryption, defensive-programming

A question that I have been wondering for quite some time now, is how do two devices send encrypted data over the internet know the encryption keys to encrypt and decrypt the data, or more importantly how do these services automate the encryption?

Do these services have non changing encryption keys that all their users use, or do they somehow hide the encryption key in the data that is sent over the internet.

If the question needs more clarification feel free to ask.

Comment: [Key exchange](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_exchange)

Answer (score -1):

In particular with SSL/TLS communication the symmetric key used for encrypting data is never sent over the wire. Both sides generate it by running algorithm over random data that is exchanged.

For complete reference, one may refer the Cipher Suite which is combination of protocol/key exchange/symmetric encryption algorithm/authentication/hashing

Example -
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256

Comment: request anyone down voting to please explain. above lines are correct.